# Phonegap-Date format not storing in db

Tags: php, sql, ajax, jquery, cordova

i am doing a phonegap app.i am trying to save date from jqm date picker to db..but in dbt my saved date is showing 0000-00-00 format..pls help

Ajax

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'url',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {date: $('#datepicker').val()},

            success: function(data){
                   alert(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                   alert('There was an error');
```

PHP

```
<?php
  include_once('config/config.php');
   $date = $_POST['date'];
   $query = "INSERT INTO myapp(date) VALUES ('$date')";
   mysql_query($query);
   echo "Data Added";

 ?>
```

Body

```
 <form id="target" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Date">
 </form>
```

Comment: just `var_dump($date);`  after  `$date = $_POST['date'];` and show us the output ..you probably will get the output in alert box of your application

Comment: string(10) "01/13/2014"..i am getting dis alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
   include_once('config/config.php');
   $date = $_POST['date'];
   $splitDate = explode('/', $date);
   $finalDate = $splitDate[2] . '-' . $splitDate[0] . '-' . $splitDate[1];
   $query = "INSERT INTO myapp(date) VALUES ('$finalDate')";
   mysql_query($query);
   echo "Data Added";    
 ?>
```

Just replace your code with above code.
Date wasn't getting saved in database because you were trying to insert invalid date into date column of table.